# Why do bind mounts of device nodes break with EACCES in root of a tmpfs?

Tags: linux, mount, namespace, bind-mount

A common scenario for setting up a container/sandbox is wanting to create a minimal set of device nodes in a new tmpfs (rather than exposing the host `/dev`), and the only (unprivileged) way I know to do this is by bind-mounting the desired ones into it. The commands I'm using (inside `unshare -mc --keep-caps`) are:

```
mkdir /tmp/x
mount -t tmpfs none /tmp/x
touch /tmp/x/null
mount -o bind /dev/null /tmp/x/null
```

with the intend of moving the mount on top of `/dev`. However, even before doing the move, running `echo > /tmp/x/null` produces a "Permission denied" error (`EACCES`).

Yet if I additionally perform:

```
mkdir /tmp/x/y
touch /tmp/x/y/null
mount -o bind /dev/null /tmp/x/y/null
echo > /tmp/x/y/null
```

the write succeeds as it should. I've played around with this quite a bit, but can't find a root cause or reason this should be happening. It's possible to work around it by putting the bind-mounted nodes in a subdirectory and symlinks to them in the top-level of the filesystem that will become the new `/dev`, but it seems like this shouldn't be necessary.

What's going on? Is there a reasonable explanation for this? Or is it some access control logic gone wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, this seems to be a very interesting effect, which is a consequence of three mechanisms combined together.

The first (trivial) point is that when you redirect something to the file, the shell opens the target file with the `O_CREAT` option to be sure that the file will be created if it does not yet exist.

The second thing to consider is the fact that `/tmp/x` is a `tmpfs` mountpoint, while `/tmp/x/y` is an ordinary directory. Given that you mount `tmpfs` with no options, the mountpoint's permissions automagically change so that it becomes world-writable and has a sticky bit (`1777`, which is a usual set of permissions for `/tmp`, so this feels like a sane default), while the permissions for `/tmp/x/y` are probably `0755` (depends on your `umask`).

Finally, the third part of the puzzle is the way you set up the user namespace: you instruct `unshare(1)` to map UID/GID of your host user to the same UID/GID in the new namespace. This is *the only* mapping in new namespace, so trying to translate any other UID between the parent/child namespaces will result in so-called *overflow UID*, which by default is `65534` — a `nobody` user (see `user_namespaces(7)`, section `Unmapped user and group IDs`). This makes `/dev/null` (and its bind-mounts) be owned by `nobody` inside the child user namespace (as there is no mapping for host's `root` user in the child user namespace):

```
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nobody 1, 3 Nov 25 21:54 /dev/null
```

Combining all the facts together we come to the following: `echo > /tmp/x/null` tries to open an existing file with `O_CREAT` option, while this file resides inside the world-writable sticky directory and is owned by `nobody`, who is not the owner of the directory containing it.

Now, read `openat(2)` carefully, word by word:

> EACCES
>
> Where O_CREAT is specified, the protected_fifos or protected_regular sysctl is enabled, the file already exists and is a FIFO or regular file, the owner of
> the file is neither the current user nor the owner of the containing directory, and the containing directory is both world- or group-writable  and  sticky.
> For details, see the descriptions of /proc/sys/fs/protected_fifos and /proc/sys/fs/protected_regular in proc(5).

Isn't this brilliant? This seems almost like our case... Except the fact that the man page tells **only** about ordinary files and FIFOs and tells **nothing** about device nodes.

Well, let's take a look at the [code which actually implements this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fa02fcd94b0c8dff6cc65714510cf25ad194b90d/fs/namei.c#L1069-L1090). We can see that, essentially, it first checks for exceptional cases which must succeed (the first `if`), and then it just denies the access for any other case if the sticky directory is world-writable (the second `if`, first condition):

```c
static int may_create_in_sticky(umode_t dir_mode, kuid_t dir_uid,
        struct inode * const inode)
{
  if ((!sysctl_protected_fifos && S_ISFIFO(inode->i_mode)) ||
      (!sysctl_protected_regular && S_ISREG(inode->i_mode)) ||
      likely(!(dir_mode & S_ISVTX)) ||
      uid_eq(inode->i_uid, dir_uid) ||
      uid_eq(current_fsuid(), inode->i_uid))
    return 0;

  if (likely(dir_mode & 0002) ||
      (dir_mode & 0020 &&
       ((sysctl_protected_fifos >= 2 && S_ISFIFO(inode->i_mode)) ||
        (sysctl_protected_regular >= 2 && S_ISREG(inode->i_mode))))) {
    const char *operation = S_ISFIFO(inode->i_mode) ?
          "sticky_create_fifo" :
          "sticky_create_regular";
    audit_log_path_denied(AUDIT_ANOM_CREAT, operation);
    return -EACCES;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, if the target file is a char device (not a regular file or a FIFO), the kernel still denies opening it with `O_CREAT` when this file is in the world-writable sticky directory.

To prove that I found the reason correctly, we may check that the problem disappears in any of the following cases:

- mount `tmpfs` with `-o mode=777` — this will *not* make the mountpoint have a sticky bit;
- open `/tmp/x/null` as `O_WRONLY`, but without `O_CREAT` option (to test this, write a program calling `open("/tmp/x/null", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)` and `open("/tmp/x/null", O_WRONLY)`, then compile and run it under `strace -e trace=openat` to see the returned values for each call).

I'm not sure whether this behavior should be considered a kernel bug or not, but the documentation for `openat(2)` clearly does not cover *all* the cases when this syscall *actually* fails with `EACCES`.

Comment: That function was added in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5 . It looks to me like a bug: the commit message doesn't mention anything about other types of files, and it effectively forces "protected" mode on for them.

Comment: According to the manpages, the original assumption which this restriction is based upon is that the caller may _intend_ to create the file with `O_CREAT`, while this file may already be created by an attacking user (thus, fooling the caller of `openat`). Given that device nodes are not supposed to be created automatically with `O_CREAT` (so `O_CREAT` for devices in `openat` does not actually imply the intention to create the file), I believe that (probably) there is no reason for denying such calls for device nodes.

Comment: In other words, I also would consider this a bug, but I'm not a kernel developer, so that's just a passer-by's opinion.

Comment: @DanilaKiver: That should only apply to `O_EXCL` not `O_CREAT`.

Comment: Ah, I see the whole point of these restrictions is for the sake of broken applications that omit `O_EXCL`. In any case, WOW, thank you for this deep explanation. It's perfect and you totally deserve the bounty, which I've awarded.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to award it and thought I did, but can't yet. Will do once the waiting period expires.